# Android: Why doesn't the UserDictionary.Words extend the ContentProvider class?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-userdictionary

From the [developer guide of Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)s:

> Android itself includes content providers that manage data such as
>   audio, video, images, and personal contact information.

From the [developer guide of Content Provider Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Permissions):

> one of the *built-in providers in the Android platform* is the user
>   dictionary, which stores the spellings of non-standard words that the
>   user wants to keep.

From the [Javadoc of ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)):

> Known Direct Subclasses DocumentsProvider, FileProvider,
>   MockContentProvider, SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider

From the [API documentation of UserDictionary.Word](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.Words.html#CONTENT_URI)s:-

> java.lang.Object
>       ↳ android.provider.UserDictionary.Words

They are saying that Android Platform comes with some built-in content providers. Then say that Android platform has a built-in provider user dictionary. **Secondly, if we implement our own content provider, even then we subclass ContentProvider class, right?**

**So why doesn't UserDictionary.Words content provider extent the ContentProvider class?**

Comment: and what for? do you know how to use CPs? we do not using 'em directly only via ContentResolver ... the subclasses of CP are for subclassing specialized versions of CP ... the UserDictionary.Words class is only helper class for accessing of user dictionary CP(similar to Contacts.*/ContactsContract.* classes)

Comment: @Selvin "the UserDictionary.Words class is only helper class for accessing of user dictionary CP"- thank you, this makes it clear. If you can write it as answer, I can mark it as accepted, will help future visitors.